# Change points in the mean and in the variance using R

Tags: r, change-point

Hi I am trying to check the existence of change points in the mean and in the variance using R. My data is not normally distributed, so I want to use the cusum test. Also I want the significance level to be 0.05.

I am trying to use the package "changepoints", but for change points in the mean I couldn't find a way of choosing the significance level because it says the asymptotic penalty is not available with cusum!

For the variance it lets me choose the significance level using:
`single.var.css(x,penalty="Asymptotic",value=0.05,class=TRUE,param.estimates=TRUE)`
however it always detects a change point. Sometimes it looks like a real changepoint, but when the series doesn't seem to have one it just detects a change point in the end of the series.

Anyone knows a way of calculating change points in R using the cusum test with a significance level of 0.05?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Since the problem is resolved, I've cleared this comment thread.

Comment: @mbq, but how the problem was resolved? Was the solution in the comment thread?

Comment: It was about cross-posting of the question; no answer was there.

Comment: If it's not normally distributed, the variance is probably not a good metric. Maybe the inter-quartile range?